# Follow scrollbar all the way down as DIV overflows?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, overflow

So I have made this script that pushes text from .txt document line per line at different time stamps with jQuery. The problem is that once DIV is filled up, updates keep coming but are not visible unless visitor scrolls down. Is there any way to keep scollbar fixed at the bottom so it follows all the updates?

Also it'd be great addition to randomize the text pulled from my kaka.txt, so it doesn't always go by the same order.

Here is my script:

```
    <div class="kaka" style="height: 200px; width: 300px;">


  <?php include('kaka.txt'); ?>


 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

   var pirmais = $('.kaka div:first-child');
   pirmais.fadeIn().addClass('toms');
   pirmais.next().addClass('sitais');
   var kaka = function() {
    $('kaka div').not('.toms').hide();
    var nakam = $('.sitais');
    var pedejais = nakam.attr('pedejais');
    if (pedejais == '1') {
     $('.kaka div').clone().appendTo('.kaka').removeClass('toms').hide();
    }
    else {

    }
    nakam.fadeIn().addClass('toms');
    $('.kaka div').removeClass('sitais');
    nekst = nakam.next().addClass('sitais');
   };
   (function loop() {
       var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
       setTimeout(function() {
               kaka();
               loop();  
       }, rand);
}());
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following like just after nekst = nakam.next().addClass('sitais');

$('.kaka').animate({scrollTop: $('.kaka').attr('scrollHeight')});

Comment: Thank you, it ALMOST worked - but this addition fixes at the top position, I need it at the bottom.

Comment: try $('.kaka')[0].scrollTop($('.kaka')[0].scrollHeight)

Comment: if it did not work also then use $('.kaka').animate({scrollTop: $('.kaka').attr('scrollHeight')});

Comment: Awesome, now it works perfectly! Can't thank you enough Manish!